# Holder.js and Rails routing?

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails-3, asset-pipeline

How can I use [Holder.js](http://imsky.github.com/holder/) in my Rails app? The parameters are passed to the script via slashes, which Rails is picking up as a route and returning 404's at me... anyone got this working?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use the `data-src` attribute instead of `src`, i.e. `<img data-src="holder.js/200x200">`.

Answer (score 3):

Alternatively, you can use [`holder_rails` gem](https://github.com/NARKOZ/holder_rails#readme).